# URLSearchParams is not a constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, http-headers, angular-httpclient

I have a Angular Service, where I try to send a HTTP Post request and set the 
`Content-Type` Header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

This is the code:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
export class UserService {
    constructor(private http:HttpClient, private bodyParser:BodyParserService{}

    public login(username:String, password:String){
        let body = this.bodyParser.parseBody({username: username, password: password})
        const options = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})

        };
         this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/login`, body, options)
        .subscribe((response:any) => {
           console.log("Response", response);
        })
    }

}
```

I am using Angular7. I use the Chrome Browser, but the issue persists on FireFox

I get the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: url__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.URLSearchParams is not a constructor
at BodyParserService.push../src/app/services/body-parser.service.ts.BodyParserService.parseBody (body-parser.service.ts:12)
at UserService.push../src/app/services/user-service.service.ts.UserService.login (user-service.service.ts:21)
at LoginModalComponent.push../src/app/nav-bar/nav-bar.component.ts.LoginModalComponent.login (nav-bar.component.ts:50)
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (LoginModalComponent.html:19)
at handleEvent (core.js:19545)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:20639)
at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:20342)
at dispatchEvent (core.js:16994)
at core.js:17441
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:993)
```

I have made sure, that I have importet the HttpClientModule

The bodyParser Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { URLSearchParams } from 'url';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BodyParserService {

   constructor() { }

  public parseBody(bodyObject: Object): string {
    const body = new URLSearchParams();
    Object.keys(bodyObject).forEach(key => {
      body.set(key.toString(), bodyObject[key]);
    });
    return body.toString();
  }
}
```

Okay I have found my mistake:
URLSearchParams seems to be deprecated. I have used the HttpParams instead now:

```
const body = new HttpParams();
```

Comment: What is this `BodyParserService` that you're using?

Comment: Updated the question.

The service gets an object and parses it into a string

Answer (score 4):

URLSearchParams is deprecated, you must use HttpParams. For example

```
let params = new HttpParams()
  .set('grant_type', 'password')
  .set('username', username)
  .set('password', password);

params.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added the right solution to the answer. URLSearchParams seems to be deprecated. So I switched to the `HttpParams` wich seems to work flawlessly